# Click event not working only when used in external JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

when used in external main.js (see content below), only the "ready!!" text shows up. But when used inline without referencing the main.js (see below too) both "ready!!" and "clicked!!" text are displayed. Any idea why did I miss here ?

**page content case 1**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">    
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>    
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://mywpblog.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.2'></script>    
</head>    
<body>
    <button class="purchase-test" type="button"></button>    
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://mywpblog.com/wp-content/plugins/mytestplugin/assets/js/main.js?ver=3.0.1'></script>
</body>    
</html>
```

**page content case 2**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">    
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://mywpblog.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.2'></script>
</head>    
<body>
    <button class="purchase-test" type="button"></button>
    <script>
        JQuery(document).ready(function() {
            console.log("ready!!"); // WOKRS FINE
            JQuery('.purchase-test').click(function(e) {
                console.log("clicked!!"); // WOKRS FINE AS WELL
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
JQuery(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("ready!!"); // WOKRS FINE
    JQuery('.purchase-test').click(function(e) {
        console.log("clicked!!"); // DOES NOT WORK
    });
});
```

Comment: are you sure the scripts are placed at the bottom of the page before body ends?

Comment: Why are you calling the jquery script twice?

Comment: Yes Steve, be sure the `.purchase-test` elements are available.

Comment: yes of course and jQuery is in the header

Comment: Is `.purchase-test` added with JS? Try console logging `$('.purchase-test')`. If its length is 0, the element didn't exist at that point yet.

Comment: What is .purchase-test is it a link?

Comment: it's a button like in the example above

Comment: Try to use `$` or `jQuery` instead of `JQuery` in your main.js

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('.purchase-test').on("click", function(event) {
        // If '.purchase-test' is a link: 
        // <a href="" class="purchase-test">A Link</a>
        // You must preventDefault
        event.preventDefault()

        // Log to console
        console.log("Clicking Purchase test");
    });
    $('.non-purchase-test').on("click", function(event) {
       console.log("Clicking Non Purchase Test");
    });
    $(".purchase-test-button").on("click", function(event) {
       console.log("Clicking on Button"); 
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cpcmn41z/1/